# Firebase query with simple login

Tags: firebase

I am trying to query firebase where I have used simple login to differentiate between users.  As such firebase looks like this:

`users/simplelogin:*/favouritecolour`

`favouritecolour` looks like `{0: blue, 1: red, 2: green}`

I want to be able to query for all users with the same `favouritecolour` and send their profile information back to be displayed on the web page.

`users/simplelogin:*/profileinformation`

The problem I have is that simple login uses authData.uid for "simplelogin:*" and as such it is different for each user.  I want to look through all users.  I am not sure how to reference the path to just the `favouritecolour` for each user, as when querying I don't want to have to search the entire database.  I have looked for a wildcard token to use in the path name.  I have also looked at relative path definitions, where one may be able to skip over branches in a path.  No luck.  What code do I need to write to return `profileinformation` as a snapshot for all profiles matching `favouritecolour` red?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Umut's answer is correct. Additionally, If you are going to 'look through' (i.e. query) your users for favorite color data, you are also going to want to keep your data as 'flat' as possible because Firebase queries only go one level deep. So you need to keep the users favorite color as a direct child of their uid.  users/uid1/favoritecolor,   users/uid2/favoritecolor   etc. with favoriteColor = "Blue" or whatever color it is. There are a number of examples posted of how to flatten and query for data in Firebase so looking through those would be a good next step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to organize data according to how they are going to be accessed, not according to how "it makes sense" in traditional relational DB. This also includes data duplication and non-normalization.

Take a look at [this](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html).

So, you also need to keep something like this:

`/favouritecolor/{color}/  --> { user1, user2, user3 }`